# inkwell ontab does not work when clicking on the form

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I use the [searchField](https://pub.dev/packages/searchfield), judging by the documentation, there should be an onTab field in the searcField widget, but apparently the library has been updated and there is no such function anymore, since I need to trigger an event in the block when clicking on the field, I decided to wrap the widget in inkwell, but when clicked, nothing works and the event does not called

```
BlocBuilder<FillprofileBloc, FillprofileState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    return InkWell(
                      focusColor: Colors.transparent,
                      onTap: () {
          
                        _bloc.add(OnCitySearchTabEvent());
                        
                      },
                      child: SearchField(
                          searchInputDecoration: InputDecoration(
```

Comment: I think the onTap function is changed to onSuggestionTap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround with  `GestureDetector`.

```dart
GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
  onPanDown: (_) {
    debugPrint("pan down");
  },
  child: SearchField(),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use onTap param of TextField itself here. Or wrap your TextField with IgnorePointer to use InkWell

Comment: I'm not using a regular textfield, but a searchfield that doesn't have an onTab